# Html.BeginRouteForm is being redirected to wrong action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Forums_default", new { action = "RewardPost", item = Model.PostId }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "reward" }))
```

Now, those are my routes:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Forums_thread",
    "Forums/{action}/{category}/{item}",
    new { controller = "Forums" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Forums_category",
    "Forums/{category}",
    new { controller = "Forums", action = "ThreadList" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Forums",
    "Forums/",
    new { controller = "Forums", action = "CategoryList" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Forums_default",
    "Forums/{action}/{item}",
    new { controller = "Forums", action = "CategoryList", item = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This is the form that is being generated:

```
<form action="/Forums/RewardPost/11" class="reward" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">...
</form>
```

And this is where it redirects me: `/Forums/AddPost/4`

Now the question: What is going on here? How do i fix this?

Comment: Is the `RewardPost` action being invoked? Are you redirecting inside it? When submitting a form the browser will send the request to the url specified in its `action` attribute which is `/Forums/RewardPost/11`.

Comment: Nope. Breakpoint isn't even hit...

Comment: is there more than 1 form on that view?